# Git Bash command not found after installing a package

Tags: windows, node.js, git, bash, npm

I'm using msysgit on Windows, whenever I install something i.e. Node.js or a package via NPM I always get command not found until the system is rebooted. Even closing git bash and reopening I have the same issue. I've set environment paths for npm and node:

```
C:\Ruby200\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Predator\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

**Edit:**

For example using Git Bash window I have Node.Js and NPM installed. I want to install a package globally so run:

```
npm install grunt -g
```

Grunt then installs globally, I then check grunt is installed by running

```
grunt --version
```

Error produced is:

```
sh: grunt: command not found
```

This happens with all NPM packages, it even happened with node.js and npm when I installed them. How can I restart Git Bash to take into account the newly installed packages?

Comment: what command is not found?

Comment: whatever has just been installed on the system. i.e. if I install a package via npm using 'npm install grunt -g', then try and request grunt in the cli it will say 'sh: grunt: command not found'.

Comment: please add this to your question; will make it more clear..

Comment: normally you don't need to restart bash. It should look automatically in all your binary paths... check if the binary (eg grunt) is present in one of the locations you put in the environment path...

Answer (score 1):

To add say `C:\Program Files\nodejs` to the path inside the shell, you would issue:

```
PATH="C:/Program\ Files/nodejs;$PATH"
export PATH
```

in some shells you can combine those two commands in one:

```
export PATH="C:/Program\ Files/nodejs;$PATH"
```

to look to see what folders are currently searched:

```
echo $PATH
```

You may be able to get the shell to reread the environment giving the `-l` option when you run the shell. See what your shell is by running:

```
echo $SHELL
```

If you get something, then try running:

```
$SHELL -l
```

which starts another login shell. However better is to use:

```
exec $SHELL -l
```

which starts a new shell replacing the old one. Without "exec" you'll have the new shell nested inside the old one, which might not be so bad.